# How to put placeholder in DateTimePickerFor in kendo mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to add placeholder some thing like "Select Date.." instead of showing the default date which is current date.

Here my client side view but it didn't work.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DateTimePickerFor(m => m.StartOn)
 .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px", placeholder = "Select Date.."}))
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have the same code working. What are you getting? My DateTime field is null when it displays.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your StartOn DateTime property a nullable DateTime (DateTime?) to have a blank input which will allow the placeholder to be visible.